# Is it possible to pass variables from the controller to the view and create multiple different URLs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have only recently begun using MVC. I have a situation in my view where I need to create several different links to several different places. Currently I am using a switch statement using their type as a parameter, and writing them out individually. Example here:

```
switch (link.Type)
{ 
    case "type1": %>                                   
        <a href='<%= Url.RouteUrl("A", new { controller = "Controller1", action = "Action1", 
        param1 = x, param2 = y, newWindow = "yes" }) %>' target="_blank"><%: link.Name %></a> <%

    break;

    case "type2": %>
        <a href='<%= Url.RouteUrl("B", new { controller = "Controller2", action = "Action2", 
        param1 = x, param2 = y, newWindow = "yes" }) %>' target="_blank"><%: link.Name %></a> <%

    break;
}
```

As you can see from the example above, there are only very minor changes between the URLs. I believe I will have 10-20 of these types, and obviously solution where I would only have this once on the page would be ideal.

Is it possible to pass in variables to replace "A", "Controller1", "Action1"?

**EDIT1**: Erik already nailed my question but out of curiosity, is it also possible to supply parameter names through variables as well? So instead of having a parameter called "param2" I could have "param2" or "param3" decided through a variable?

**EDIT2**:
x and y in the example are ints that the used when the Url.RouteUrl link is clicked.

So for example, I have my two parameters that are projectId and recordId in my application. When the user clicks a link they are taken to a different controller/view and proceed from there. projectId is consistent in all links, but sometimes instead of recordId it might be tableId, articleId, etc. Is there a way to deal with these different parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is a Acronym for Model, View and Controller.  The Controller should more often then not, create a Model and pass it into the view:

So you might have a class like:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
   public string SomeString { get; set; }
   public string Controller { get; set; }
   public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

Then a controller like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var model = new IndexViewModel();
  model.SomeString = "A";
  model.Controller = "Controller1";
  model.Action = "Action1";

  return View(model);
}
```

Then the view:

```
@model IndexViewModel

<a href='<%= Url.RouteUrl(Model.SomeString, 
  new { controller = Model.Controller, 
        action = Model.Action, 
        param1 = x, param2 = y, newWindow = "yes" }) %>' 
        target="_blank"><%: link.Name %></a>
```

Update 1: You can't assign a value to a class in the constructor/initializer of an anonymous class.

```
var myvar = new MyClass;

var myanon = new { x = 1, MyClass.Prop = 2 };
//------------------------^
// You can't do this, it doesn't make sense
```

Update 2:  The [UrlHelper.RouteUrl() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492715%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) has a number of overrides.  Instead of trying to dynamically create an object for the signature `RouteUrl(String, Object)` use the signature `RouteUrl(String, RouteValueDictionary)`:

model:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
   public string SomeString { get; set; }
   public RouteValueDictionary RouteValues { get; set; }
}
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var model = new IndexViewModel();
  model.SomeString = "A";
  model.RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
  model.RouteValues.Add("Controller", "Controller1");
  model.RouteValues.Add("Action", "Action1");
  model.RouteValues.Add("param1", x);
  model.RouteValues.Add("param2", y);


  return View(model);
}
```

view:

```
@model IndexViewModel

<a href='<%= Url.RouteUrl(Model.SomeString, 
                          Model.RouteValues) %>' 
        target="_blank"><%: link.Name %></a>
```

Comment: Your answer got me on the right track with my code and seems to have fixed my issue! On a side note, if say I have a type that does not have param2, but has param3 instead, is there a way to also supply this in as a variable?

Comment: You can extend the model however you wish.  You can add lists of strings, ints, whatever you want.  Are you asking, how can I create a model with optional properties, and then use the correct properties easily?

Comment: I understand what your saying, though it seems that introducing something like:

    param1 = x, Model.Param = y, newWindow = "yes" }) %>'

is a boo boo, with an error mentioning anonymous type member declaration.

Comment: A. you can't assign an instantiated class's property a value during the constructor/instantiation of an anonymous class (update 1).  B. I don't know where your `x` and `y` values come from.

Comment: I added an edit to my original question, hoping to clarify what I mean. If this isn't possible that is fine, it is more of a nice to have.

Comment: Yes, now I understand your question.  I've updated my Answer.

Comment: That  UrlHelper method did everything I needed it to, it works fantastic. Thanks for the help Erik!

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
     var model = new IndexViewModel();
     ViewBag.Link1="A";
     ViewBag.Link2="B";
     ViewBag.Link13"C";
     ViewBag.Link3="D";
     return View("ViewName",model);
    }
```

Inside View
//.Link1

```
if(ViewBag.Link1)
{
}
if(ViewBag.Link2)
{
}
if(ViewBag.Link3)
{
}
if(ViewBag.Link4)
{
}
```